# HTML/PHP - Wrong closing tag order

Tags: html, browser, tags

Of course, this tag is NOT correct :

```
<b><i>Hi</b></i>
```

However, it still runs perfectly in modern browsers (at least in newest version of chrome).

What is the negative effect for this wrong order of code?

Also, look at this :

```
<table><tr><td>Hi</td></table></tr>
```

How will the browsers treat THIS code?

Comment: Dont use `<b><i>` at all. Use CSS instead. (has nothing to do with the question though just mentioning it)

Comment: @Daan you can't say that not knowing the context.

Comment: If you really want to know how browsers parse bad HTML, [read the parsing rules in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing). You really should only need to worry about them if you are writing an HTML parser though, content authors should just write good HTML in the first place (and test it with a [validator](http://validator.w3.org)).

Comment: Yes, @Daan, but I am making a chat box. `<b>` will be more convenient then adding `style="text-weight:bold"`, so I personally agree with @enapupe.

Comment: It's not recommended to use inline styles in that way either.  You could use <strong> (better than <b> in my opinion) or you use a span with a class based on the meaning of the content (e.g. messageHeading or something).  This means that if you at some point want that text to be underlined/larger/red/normal/etc instead of bold you only have to change one place in the CSS instead of chaning all the places you use it.  It also means that you can easily add multiple stylings, style differnetly for print, etc

Comment: In terms of the actual question about misformed HTML: browsers will do their best but never rely on that.  Write your HTML correctly, especially nesting correctly.  Really weird layout (and occassionally javascript or even form submit, especially in IE) problems can arise from misformed HTML and they are always a nightmare to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers will try to assume what you are trying to do with your code.
From my humble understanding about browsers this is what I noticed:

Every opening tag will have a closing tag.
Every closing tag must have an opening tag, if not, then there's no need to have that closing tag. 
If a closing tag is missing, the browser will complete your code for you and add a closing tag (*this is the tricky part*).

Most likely the closing tag will be before opening a new section or new tags collection.

If your code is:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
       Hi
    </td> 
  </table> 
</tr>
```

Then it will be interpreted as:

```
<table>//opening OK
  <tr>//opening OK
    <td>//opening OK
       Hi
    </td>//closing an opened tag - OK
  </table>//closing table, we still have <tr> opened, close <tr> first by adding </tr> before this tag /*now '<tr>' has been closed already and then </table> is closed*/     
</tr>//this closing tag doesn't have an opening, remove it.
```

Syntax auto correction results in:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
       Hi
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some browsers, however, like IE7 will treat that differently. It won't know what your intention is and which element is the parent of another.

**In the following example, assume we forgot to close tag `<b>`. Now, should `<c>` be a child of `<b>` or a sibling?**

```
<a>
 <b> // doesn't have a closing
  <c>
  </c>
</a>
```

Firefox and Chrome treated `<b>` and `<c>` as sibling as I intended and displayed all items, but in IE7 it only displayed one item because it assumed `<c>` is a child of `<b>`.

Therefore I assumed that firefox and chrome closed `<b>` for me before the opening of `<c>` which was my intention.

While IE included everything after the opening of `<b>` as children of `<b>` itself making all the subsequent element fall under `<b>` and displayed only one list item.

Firefox and Chrome:

```
<a>
 <b>
 </b> // auto close here as expected
 <c>
 </c>
</a>
```

IE:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
  </c>
 </b>//auto close, they closed <b> just before closing the parent <a> logical but somehow falsy!
</a>
```

Hope that helps, and I hope that my understanding is somehow accurate.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the browser will try to understand what you meant.

The "negative effect" is unpredictability.

Comment: Fair enough. You may break the internet.