# In HTML; why should <a> tag start inside a paragraph, but end outside of it?

Tags: html

I was going through some alison.com materials on web development and one of their questions was:

True or False - The following code is formatted correctly.

```
<p><br>
<a href="">Click here<br>
</p><br>
</a>
```

The right answer is True.

But why the < a > tags' ending-tag < /a > is outside of the paragraph < p > tag?

Comment: It's not formatted correctly. Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: they are simply wrong .. even if some browser will render this in a certain way but it remain wrong

Comment: The post editor supports html, please use the correct formatting of your code by indenting it four spaces.

Comment: Any tag should be completed within its containing tag, so this is wrong.

Comment: It's **not** formatted correctly but actually most modern browsers will try to fix the incorrect formatting. Check this: [Wrong closing tag order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109754/html-php-wrong-closing-tag-order)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm new in this community so sorry for those rookie -mistakes.

I had to check if they were wrong or if I was just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<br>
<p><a href="">Click here<br></a></p>
<br>
```

Something like this is the correct way

Comment: Maybe, although the `<br>`s look fishy to me. Their semantic purpose does not look as if they are injecting line breaks in a paragraph - perhaps they are just there to add more vertical space. If so, they should be removed and CSS applied to the paragraph.